# A word for defining inspirational artwork

Tags: single-word-requests

Unfortunatelly I forgot this word totally, and I am tring to remember it for sometime but could not succeed. So this word is used to define inspiration artwork, which is not related to the same concept of the original source.

For example we all know the batman movie. If I create a graphic design like below, what does it called?

[image]

Or another design like this which is inspired by star wars?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how the first one is inspirational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parody, or perhaps better, spoof:

> A parody (/ˈpærədi/; also called a spoof, send-up, take-off, or lampoon) is a work created to imitate, make fun of, or comment on an original work—its subject, author, style, or some other target—by means of satiric or ironic imitation.

Source: Wikipedia